# How it works with multiple subscription package have same period and different price?

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I found that Capcut on Appstore there are 4 subscriptions "capcut cloud space" with 4 different prices.

It shows all packages in iCloud > Subscription. What happen if I subscribe the most cheapest?

[image]

Is it feasible to show selected subscription to users? Such a scenario, I run promotion to specific users and not allow another users.

I cannot find out any related documents about this thing

Answer (score 0):

Apple has listed several ways to set up discounts and promotions [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/#offering-introductory-prices).

For implementing promotions using StoreKit, you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/original_api_for_in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/implementing_promotional_offers_in_your_app).

Comment: I got your point, but it's not fit to my purpose. 
I'd promote new price for whole time instead of promo in short time